# Touchpad Doesn't Work on HP Spectre x360 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, hp

I successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new HP Spectre x360 Convertible (after a variety of installation issues relating to graphics). However, the touchpad is not working. An external USB mouse works fine.

This is the output of `xinput --list` (with the USB mouse attached):

[image: Output of xinput --list]

And this is the output of `lsusb`:

[image: Output of lsusb]

What can I do to get it to recognize the touchpad?

Comment: I should add that the touchpad works fine in Windows 10 (I installed Ubuntu as dual-boot) and it also works fine under Ubuntu running in a VM in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on end of 2018 model (diamond cut) with Nvidia GTX 1050, just to install you will have to edit (`e`) grub line while starting from uEFI Ubuntu pen drive and add at the end:

```
i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop
```

then after you finished with installation and starting new system you might need to press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to switch to console and add that to `/etc/default/grub` at the end of line **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`**.

My whole grub line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2009\" acpi_enforce_resources=lax i915.alpha_support=1 i915.modeset=1 intel_pstate=enable rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau elevator=deadline i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

Comment: Do the touchpad and touchscreen both work for you under 18.04?

Comment: Thanks for the above. I was able to get the touchpad working by adding those additional parameters to my grub line (i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop).

However, the touchscreen still doesn't work. Were you able to get yours working?

Comment: Try installing wacom driver: apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom.

Comment: BTW with Ubuntu 18.04.02 and kernel 4.18.0-17-generic most of problems goes away. Now my grub command line looks: ....ro acpi_enforce_resources=lax elevator=deadline

Comment: One last thing to sort out on my x360 (2019) is suspend. Been very busy. Try to remember to send update on that, when I will find some time to sort it out.